Discrepancy in viewing the web page in the index file. html and in my non-Gitbuh repository
It turns out that the images look good in the index.html file, and they are not seen in the repository, make the modifications both in the file and in the repository. from bash I applied the same command to synchronize, and nmo worked.

Esto es SO en ESPAÑOL por favor traduce tu problema o dirigete a [SO]
